# Why should Kubera(a Yaksha) worshipped, when real goddess of wealth is Shri Laxmi?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, puranas, kubera

Kubera is a Yaksha, so why should he worshipped and not alone Goddess Laxmi for granting us wealth? Which scriptures asks to worship Kubera and why?

Comment: BTW Kubera is worshipped after Sri Lakshmi. i think She is related to coming of wealth and Kuber to holding of it.Lakshmi is chanchalaa